# Bootstrap vertical form: label and input with different widths

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

While using Bootstrap I'm having some trouble setting a different width for a form's label and input.

Actually, I can do what I want, but I think there's probably a better way. My current "solution" is to add a new `div.row` and then an additional `div.form-group` for making the `input` smaller, but it adds additional unwanted markup and messes with other stuff (form-validation indicators).

Any good solution for what I'm looking for?

Please take a look as [this JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/subsektj/16/), to better understand my problem/goal. The 1st section includes the base case, the 2nd section includes my current solution, which I don't really like.

Comment: Question is slightly unclear. Care to explain more?

Comment: What's the correct way to set different widths for a label and an input, while using a vertical form in Boostrap?

Comment: The `input` tag has its contextual classes - `input-lg`, `input-md`, `input-sm`, etc...

Comment: `input-lg`, `input-md`, etc affect height, not width.